# Creating a unique integer based on 3 different integers

Tags: java, hash, int, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

**I'd like to create an `int` called `hash` in Java, from the coordinates `x`, `y` and `w`.**

The values of `x` and `y` are signed and often negative.

The size of an `int` is 32 bits.

I'd like to assign 4 bits to `w` (or 3 if the most significant bit isn't usable), 14 bits to `x` and 14 bits to `y`.

I have tried the following method and I do not understand why the values clash at all: `w + x << 4 + y << 18`.

For example, `x = 1` clashes with `y = 1` when `w == 0`.

**The advantages of doing this are as follows:**

- Quick to look up in a database
- Quicker to compare a single integer, rather than three of them
- The allocated number of bits for each integer are never exceeded anyway

Comment: Share your code. What problems are you having?

Comment: with an x and a y you can always use % and / to get x/y from a single integer. When it comes to adding another parameter however it confuses things. Your best bet is to store a String with the values in static positions then use your code to parse and read the values.
so for w,x,y of 2, 123,124 you could have the value 020012300124 and use the code to determin that the w contains 02, the x oo123 and the y 00124.

Comment: @nicomp, the only relevant code here is a one liner, which I did share.

Comment: @Anton, I wouldn't the comparisons be significantly slower?

Comment: @Lolums slower than what? If you want to store 3 values in one field you have to separate them somehow

Comment: @Anton, a string, e.g. `W,XXXX,YYYY` vs a 32 bit integer

Comment: A string would be easier to parse but both would work

Comment: no, if you want my recommendation its not to do this at all. 3 values in one filed is awfull, but my opinion was not the question...

Comment: @Anton, it does not need parsing. The only things that matter are comparisons - this is for performance.

Comment: @Anton it's a hash, of course they're all together in one integer, that's the point

Comment: ah maybe I picked up the wrong idea with this one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem here is operator precedence. + goes before <<, so you have to write it like this:

```
w + (x << 4) + (y << 18)
```

This doesn't confine `w` or `x` to their allotted fields, but that doesn't do bad things with the hash value. If you had used `|` to combine them, it would be a bad hash when `w` or `x` get negative, but it's fine with `+`.

Comment: That's really surprising and I would have never guessed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is *operator precedence*: `+` takes precedence over `<<`, so your expression

```
w + x << 4 + y << 18
```

is equivalent to

```
((w + x) << (4 + y)) << 18
```

Try this:

```
w + (x << 4) + (y << 18)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int hash =  w << 28 | (x & 0x3FFF) << 14 | y & 0x3FFF;
```

`+` is not a bitwise operator. This will make it look like this:

```
11110000000000000011111111111111
w -^ X          -^ Y          -^
```